# How to set up SPF DNS Record for a domain name?

Tags: email, dns, spf

I am bit confused with setting up SPF DNS Record. I followed what others suggested on their website as a solution. After setting up SPF TXT DNS Record and waiting for sometime, I tested my domain name for SPF Record on the website MXToolBox, but it keeps reporting SPF DNS Record not found. However, without WWW for my domain, MXToolBox website reports SPF DNS Record is found. Have a look at the images in the bottom. I hope someone could explain to me why this is.

SPF TXT Record

[image]

MXToolBox Website Result with and without www for our domain.
[image]

But if you go to MXToolBox overall summery page for your domain, it says You have no SPF TXT Record at all.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a small amount of confusion here. You show the results from looking up `www.rel-tek.com`, and indeed that does not have an SPF record, which is correct. I expect that mxtoolbox may be seeing an old version of your DNS.

When I check SPF for your bare domain, it succeeds, just as you've configured it:

```
# dig +short txt rel-tek.com                                                                                                          
"v=spf1 mx ip4:96.236.199.65 ~all"
```

You should not expect your `www` host to have an SPF record, nor should it have an `mx` of its own.

One tip: when you make changes to your DNS, reduce the TTL to say 300 (5 minutes). This makes it much easier to see changes, and stops bad settings from sticking around in caches for too long, letting you fix mistakes more easily. If you use `dig` on a command line (install the `dnsutils` package on Debian linuxen), you can tell it to target your home name server so you can bypass all the secondary caches and see what your real DNS is serving, so for you you might say:

```
dig +short txt @ns75.worldnic.com rel-tek.com
```

Comment: "when you make changes to your DNS, reduce the TTL to say 300 (5 minutes)." This is not enough, but depends on how the constellation of authoritative nameservers are provisioned. If they are using DNS AXFR/IXFR and not DNS NOTIFY message you need also to lower the SOA REFRESH value BEFORE changing the TTL value. So 1) change the REFRESH 2) wait up to old value of REFRESH 3) change the TTL 4) wait up to old value of the TTL 5) change the data and then 6+) do all the previous in reverse. And if you introduce new records you should change the SOA NEGATIVE value, which is the "negative" TTL.

Comment: Those are about zone transfers between primary and secondary, not requests for individual records, where reducing TTL works well enough, and none of that applies if you're querying your primary DNS directly anyway, as I suggested. Most DNS providers these days are in control of both primary and secondary, so changes tend to be applied everywhere at once (since they have inside knowledge) - they have little to gain by not doing that.

Comment: "Those are about zone transfers between primary and secondary, not requests for individual records," and where do you think the recursive nameservers will ask the records? To all authoritative nameservers, that is the primary as well as secondaries, it is load balacing, not failover. IF you change the TTL at the primary but this change of TTL happens only 24hours later at the secondary then any recursive nameserver asking the secondary will neither see the change, nor the lowered TTL...

Comment: " they have little to gain by not doing that."  DNS setups are as many as there are providers. ALso a given domain can use more than one provider. Like I said at the beginning of my comment: it depends on how the constellation of authoritative nameservers are provisioned. I was just giving extra information that is often forgotten (since people also tend to forget that all nameservers are queried, as it is load balancing not fail over)

Comment: If you do your test asking authoritative nameservers, the TTL does not matter at all: as soon as you reconfigure the authoritative nameserver with new zone content and reload it then if you ask it it will give you the new data, whatever TTL was before.

Comment: I can't enter anything below 3600 for TTL. However, finally everything seem to work for what I was trying to do; clearly identifying that our emails from our mail server is not a SPAM or JUNK mail. It works. Our mails are going into recipients inbox folder instead of spam folder. Thank you.